# Load Env variables into docker container running poweshell function app

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, azure-functions, environment-variables

I have a powershell azure function. But when I deploy it into the azure, de config settings are not added as enviroment variables. So my function app starts complaining about missing variables. This does not happen when you have a web app. In order to solve this I write all the variables into the docker file. But this is not a good solution, considering that I have diferent Enviroments (dev, Qa, PRD)

So There is a way to load a set of enviroment variables into the container?

Thanks in advance

Comment: app settings configured in portal should be available as env variables tho. could you share some code with us please ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the app service key vault references to pull the environment variables from key vault.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax